# Как исправить выпадения повторных слов в конечном результате

Tags: python

Количество игроков - это количество прогонов программы. Почему-то в конечном файле `rez` выпадают повторные слова, хотя не должны.
Почему так происходит и как это исправить?
В файле `proff` хранятся слова (*сепаратор* - `\n`)

```
import random

n = int(input('Количество игроков: '))
i=0
while n > i:
    i = i+1
    with open('Proff.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as source:
        l = source.readlines()
        word2 = ''
        word2 = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]

    with open('vibor.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = [ line.split() for line in f ]

    while word2 in data:
        word2 = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]
    
    f2 = open("vibor.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
    f2.write(word2)
    f2.close()

    my_file = open("rez.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
    my_file.write(word2)
    my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, что у вас в `data` получается. Сдаётся мне, что у вас там получается *список списков*, а не просто список слов. То есть что-то типа `[['слово1'],['слово2'],...]`, а не `['слово1','слово2',...]`

Читайте лучше файл `vibor.txt` вот так, аналогично другому файлу, который вы читаете ранее, и тогда сравнение должно нормально заработать:

```
with open('vibor.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! 3 дня не мог разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно там хранятся одинаковые слова, т.к. файл `rez.txt` открыт в режиме `a` **(append)**.
Сделайте режим `w`**(write)**.

Ну либо если в `rez.txt` должны хранится все слова со всех игр (или как это правильнее сказать), то `w+` **(write + read)** и костыль этакий:

```
my_file = open("rez.txt", 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
my_file.write('\n'.join(list(set(my_file.read().split('\n')))))
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Так тогда же будет все время 1 слово записываться, а мне нужно дополнять файл. Я прошёлся в дебаге. Проблема в моменте сравнения 'while word2 in data:' Я не совсем понимаю логику сравнения. Видимо он сравнивает слово целиком со строчкой. А как сделать что бы он сравнивал с каждым словом?

Comment: Выкатил второй вариант.